# Let $F: Ab \rightarrow Ab$ be an additive functor and $I$ a finite index set, show that $F(\sum_{i \in I} A_i) \approx \sum_{i \in I} F(A_i)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, functors

I'm self learning Algebraic Topology from Rotman's Algebraic Topology and I've come across this problem:

> Let $F: Ab \rightarrow Ab$ be an additive functor and $I$ a finite index set, show that $F(\sum_{i \in I} A_i) \approx \sum_{i \in I} F(A_i)$

I can't think of a way to start this.  Additive functors are functors such that if $f,g: B \rightarrow B'$ then $F(f + g) = F(f) + F(g)$.  I can't think of a way to show that there's an isomorphism relationship here.

Anyone have any ideas? Thorough explanations would be helpful as I'm self learning this.

Comment: Does $\Sigma$ denote direct sum? If so then use the fact that an additive functor will preserve biproduct diagrams.

Comment: Yes, $\sum$ means direct sum.  But I'm unfamiliar with byproduct diagrams, is there another way to show the isomorphism?

Comment: See Mac Lane's CFWM.

Comment: I don't have access to that book, is there a simpler way to prove this?  This problem is included in an introductory Algebraic Topology book so I assume it's possible as the author does not require Category Theory as a pre-requisite to understanding the material.

Comment: A book on algebraic topology that doesn't use category theory; it's a miracle!

Comment: Rotman's Algebraic Topology uses some Category theory, but I don't know what byproduct diagrams are and I wouldn't know how much additional Category theory I would need to learn before I could apply it to this problem.  The book seems to indicate that not a lot of Category theory is required to be able to solve this problem, so I want to be able to solve it using the  methods developed from an Algebraic Topology standpoint before looking at it from a Categorical perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be satisfied with this link to Overflow :
[Additive covariant functors preserve direct sums](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38475/additive-covariant-functor-preserve-direct-sum).

If you're interested in modules, there is proof adapted to categories of modules in "*Rings and Categories of Modules*" of F.W. Anderson and K.R. Fuller p.180. You will also find a proof for infinite index with the $Hom$   functors (which is an additive functor).